# Parsing Linked in Profiles yielded from search query using using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, optimization, linkedin-api

## **Objective**

- I'm creating a python program for webscraping Linkedin that will take in user login credentials and custom search query as inputs and use selenium to navigate the profiles yielded as results and extract data from specific webpage elements and store it in a pandas data frame.

## **Problem**

- I have provided my code below. My main concern is that it takes a long time to successfully complete a run (**approx 23 mins for parsing 68 profiles**). Could anyone please help me with optimizing the code for speed? Thanks!

## **Code**:

```
#imports

userid = "userid@domain.com"
password = "p@Ssw0rd!"
keyword = "Master of Business Data Science Otago "
url = f"https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords={keyword}&origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL&sid=RZW"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(6)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"""//*[@id="session_key"]""").send_keys(userid)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"""//*[@id="session_password"]""").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@class='sign-in-form__submit-button']").click()

driver.get(url)
links = []
scroll_target = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"background-mercado") #target for scrolling page to linked in logo at the bottom so that the 'Next' button's element becomes visible
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)',scroll_target)

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(3) 
        linky = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'app-aware-link ') #locating containers housing links in the page
        links.append([li.get_attribute('href') for li in linky[::2] if 'miniProfileUrn'in str(li.get_attribute('href'))]) #filtering only profile links from list of all links
        page_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="Next"]') #locating the 'Next' button to clik to the next page of results
        page_button.click()
    except:
        print("No more pages")

#locating and parsing indivudual elements in each profile for profile links captured
elements = { 'name': """//h1[@class="text-heading-xlarge inline t-24 v-align-middle break-words"]""",'prefix':"""//div[@class="text-body-small v-align-middle break-words t-black--light"]""",'title':"""//div[@class="text-body-medium break-words"]""",'location':"""//div[@class="text-body-small inline t-black--light break-words"]""",'see_more':"""//button[@class="inline-show-more-text__button
            inline-show-more-text__button--light
            link"]""",'about':"""//div[@class="inline-show-more-text
    
    
    
    
     full-width"]""",'experience':"""//ul[@class="pvs-list
        
        
        "]""",'expander':"""a[@class="optional-action-target-wrapper artdeco-button artdeco-button--tertiary artdeco-button--standard artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--muted 
      inline-flex justify-center full-width align-items-center artdeco-button--fluid
      
      "]"""}
profiles = []
for n in links:
    for m in n:
        driver.get(m)
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            see_mores = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, elements['see_more']) #locating 'see more' button at paragraph ends for long descriptive fields to expand them
            for s in see_mores:
                s.click()
        except:
            print("No 'see more' button")
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            expanders = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, elements['expander']) #locating expansion  buttons at to expand sections with collapsed data entries
            for e in expanders:
                e.click()
        except:
            print("No expanders")
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,elements['name']).text
        except:
            name = None
        try:
            prefix = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,elements['prefix']).text
        except:
            prefix = None
        try:
            title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,elements['title']).text
        except:
            title= None
        try:
            location = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,elements['location']).text
        except:
            location = None
        try:
            about = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,elements['about']).text
        except:
            abount = None
        try:    
            experience = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,elements['experience'])[1].text
        except:
            expereince = None
        profiles.append({'name':name,'prefix':prefix,'title':title,'about':about,'experience':experience})

#storing to a data frame and exporting to a csv
profile_df = pd.DataFrame(profiles)
profile_df.to_csv("D:\linkedin_profiles.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce execution time you can do two things.

### WebDriverWait

Replace

```
time.sleep(...)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, path)
```

with

```
WebDriverWait(driver,seconds).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path)))
```

This commands pauses execution until the element is found, and raises an exception if element is not found. By replacing `time.sleep()` you can save few seconds at each iteration.

### javascript

Replace

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, path).text
```

with javascript

```
driver.execute_script('return document.evaluate(arguments[0], document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue?.innerText;', path)
```

which executes way faster. Moreover, it returns `None` if it doesn't find the element, hence we can remove the `try except` blocks.

---

The code below is divided into two blocks. First one scrapes profile links, the second one scrapes profile data. First block took 80 seconds to scrape 40 pages and found 160 links. Second block took 82 seconds to scrape 20 profiles (I limited to 20 by using `for profile,url in enumerate(links[:20]):`), so about 4 seconds per profile. So to scrape 160 profiles it would take about 11 minutes.

About the xpaths in `elements`, I changed some of them to shorten them or because they were not correct.

Finally, I removed the code about `see_mores` and `expanders`. The first one because the full text is already present in the HTML code, so it is not needed to click "see more". The second one because if you click to expand a section, then a new page is loaded.

```
url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=Master+of+Business+Data+Science+Otago&origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL&sid=RZW'
driver.get(url)

start = time.time()
links = []
for page in range(1,999):
    print(f'{page=} {len(links)=}', end='\r')
    # wait until the results are loaded
    WebDriverWait(driver,9).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.search-results-container')))
    no_results_found = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='search-results-container']//h2[text()='No results found']")
    if no_results_found:
        print("\nNo results found")
        break
    # scroll to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    page_button = WebDriverWait(driver,9).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="Next"]')))
    if page_button.get_attribute('disabled'):
        print("\nNo more pages")
        break
    links += [a.get_attribute('href') for a in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.mb1 [href*=miniProfileUrn]')]
    page_button.click()

print(f'\nelapsed time block 1: {time.time()-start:.1f} seconds')

elements = {'name'       : "//h1",
            'prefix'     : "//span[@class='text-body-small v-align-middle break-words t-black--light']",
            'title'      : "//div[@class='text-body-medium break-words']",
            'location'   : "//span[@class='text-body-small inline t-black--light break-words']",
            'about'      : "//div[@class='...']",
            'experience' : "//div[@id='experience']/following-sibling::div[2]/ul/li"}

start = time.time()
profiles = []
for profile,url in enumerate(links):
    print(f'profile {profile+1}', end='\r')
    driver.get(url)
    # wait until the section "Experience" is loaded
    WebDriverWait(driver, 9).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section:has(#experience)')))
    name     = driver.execute_script('return document.evaluate(arguments[0], document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue?.innerText;', elements['name'])
    prefix   = driver.execute_script('return document.evaluate(arguments[0], document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue?.innerText;', elements['prefix'])
    title    = driver.execute_script('return document.evaluate(arguments[0], document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue?.innerText;', elements['title'])
    location = driver.execute_script('return document.evaluate(arguments[0], document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue?.innerText;', elements['location'])
    about    = driver.execute_script('return document.evaluate(arguments[0], document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue?.innerText;', elements['about'])
    experience = driver.execute_script("query = document.evaluate(arguments[0], document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);"+
                                       "var nodes = [];" + 
                                       "while (node = query.iterateNext()) {" +
                                       "    nodes.push(node.innerText);" + 
                                       "}"+
                                       "return nodes;", elements['experience'])
    profiles.append({'name':name,'prefix':prefix,'title':title,'location':location,'about':about,'experience':experience})

print(f'\nelapsed time block 2: {time.time()-start:.1f} seconds')

pd.DataFrame(profiles)
```

output

```
page=41 len(links)=160
No results founds
elapsed time block 1: 80.2 seconds
profile=20
elapsed time block 2: 81.8 seconds
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm a novice when it comes to python and selenium, so the changes you have implemented are all new ideas to me. Going through the code and understanding the implementation. Thanks for explaining it in detail!

Comment: @RichardTVetticad You are welcome! Anyway, what section of the page is `about`? In the code I put `//div[@class='...']` because I did not understand what it is

Comment: Oh! It's the bio section of LinkedIn profiles where we write brief summary intros. I should have put screenshots of all relevant sections for clarity